# IsNan on Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've this simple code that's test if the 1st character of the string is or not a number :

```
if (!isNaN(this.data0.username.substring(1,0)) ) {
   //Something
}
```

This actually works fine, but my editor and my linter don't like it.
It's displays:

Argument of type STRING is not assignable to parameter of type NUMBER.

Is there some how to keep the types compatible ? Or maybe a better approach to test if the 1st character of the string is or not a number ?

Waiting for suggestions !

Comment: Could you try checking the type (typeOf) rather than isNaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!isNaN(+this.data0.username.substring(1,0)) ) {
   //Something
}
```

Putting a `+` in front of the string value returns the number representation of the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Number` function :

```
if (!Number.isNaN(Number(this.data0.username.substring(1,0)))) {
   //Something
}
```